# Register each unique iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, uuid, uniqueidentifier, udid

I wish to create a User system based on each unique iOS device. This way, user don't have to register for my service and they can't delete and reinstall my app to become a "new user" again.

I wanted to use the UIDevice uniqueIdentifier but Apple has deprecated and asked us to use identifierForVendor. The problem with identifierForVendor is that if a user uninstalls my app and reinstalls it, they are view as a "new user" since the identifier changes.

OpenUDID & SecureUDID is also deprecated. Please help me solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You got it:

> Apple has deprecated and asked us to use identifierForVendor

Apple did that to prevent you from tracking down users. Some time ago you were able to ask the system for its MAC address to get a kind of identifier but Apple also changed that API: Now all devices return the same MAC address when being asked.

So short answer: There is no way left for us to get an ID that is really unique and immutable, sorry. The only way to somehow track user's is by vendor ID, as you said, or by letting them register their eMail address. Even though they could change that information when reinstalling the app.

Comment: that sucks. my app was meant to give out coupons to people who installed our app the first time. i want to track the device so that they can't abuse it. email verification will only slow them down.

Comment: And users can register multiple eMail addresses. Depending on the value of the coupon I would try a combined approach: Let them register with their eMail and also get their vendor ID - If either matches you know the user didn't install for the first time. If you're just giving away a 5$ coffee coupon your users most likely wont spend the time setting up new eMail address, reloading the app, just to save 5$ on a coffee.

Comment: If I think about it, I remenber another dev telling me Apple now provides purchase receipts not just on IAPs but also on apps. I don't know if that's true, but I will look it up for you. If that is the case you could easily prevent users from getting more than one coupon

Comment: Indeed they added such a function with iOS 7 but it doesn't seem to be well documented. Look up `NSBundle`'s `appStoreReceiptURL` method if you're interested. But do not expect too much.